# jQuery fires click events on wrong elements in IE8

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have this problem only occurring in IE8. It works fine in all the latest browsers IE10, Chrome 30, FireFox 24

Here is the Problem:
I'm setting up a click event on a selector, but it's fired on other elements, too

This is the script:

```
  $('#side-nav .nav-node-branch > a').click(function (eevent) {
    var el = $(eevent.target);
      if (el.is('#side-nav .nav-node-branch > a'))
        // all is well
      else
        // sometimes arrives here, HOW???
  }
```

Here is the simplified HTML structure:

```
<html><body>
  <nav id="side-nav">
    // 
    <ul>
      <li class="nav-node-branch"><a href="http://google.com">link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content-area">
    <form data-bind="submit: submitSearch" class="indented" novalidate="novalidate">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Bestellung für</legend>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>
                    <input checked="checked" data-bind="checked: IsEmployeeSelf" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsEmployeeSelf field is required." id="IsEmployeeSelfYes" name="IsEmployeeSelf" type="radio" value="true">
                    <label for="IsEmployeeSelfYes">Eigene Person</label>

                    <input data-bind="checked: IsEmployeeSelf" id="IsEmployeeSelfNo" name="IsEmployeeSelf" type="radio" value="false">
                    <label for="IsEmployeeSelfNo">Andere Person</label>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</body></html>
```

The handler above is triggered when clicking ANYTHING inside the form. Even the legend or just the background in the form.
Even though it should only trigger elements in the NAV. the nav is not overlapping or anything.

BTW: I am calling document.createElement('nav'); earlier

Turning off Knockout seems to fix the problem....
But the whole thing is build around knockout. So that's not really an option.
And according to http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/browser-support.html it should be supported. (knockout 3 has the same problem)

Here is a list of libraries that I'm using:

- es5-shim
- globalize
- jquery-1.10.2
- jquery-ui-1.10.3
- jquery.json-date-parser
- jQuery.mCustomScrollbar
- jQuery.mousewheel
- jquery.unobtrusive-ajax
- jquery.validate.hook
- jquery.validate
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive
- knockout-2.3.0
- modernizr-2.6.2
- mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive
- require
- ss (scriptsharp)

Comment: nav tag may not be treated properly by IE8, you can try replacing it e.g. by div

Comment: Hard to reproduce the error, as jsFiddle doesn't like IE8.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it here: http://jsbin.com/oboVATu/1, but it works fine. This only includes es5-shim, jquery, jquery-ui, and knockout. So possibly it's some interaction between Knockout and another of your libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue.
Everything resolved after moving this this little script inside a library using RequireJS:

```
$('input').keypress(function (e) {
    // If the key pressed was enter
    if (e.which == '13') {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    }
});
```

I don't think there is anything wron with this script. My theory is as follows:

I use requireJS to load all my library. This little script above however was loaded without RequireJS. My guess is, that I was operating on two different instances of jQuery. But each accessing the same jQuery Cache, which in return triggered seemingly random handlers on some elements.

**I've now ensured that all jQuery access is through RequireJS, which seems to solve the problem for me.**